# 301 Redirect on HTTPS domain

Tags: domains, dns, https, domain-forwarding

A client of mine has created some print materials with a QR code that links to `https://example1.com`. That domain does a 301 redirect to `https://example2.com`.

The redirect works when using `HTTP://example1.com`, but not `HTTPS://example1.com` (which is the URL that is attached to the QR code, so it cannot be changed).

I've purchased an SSL certificate for `example1.com`, but still didn't solve. Hosting company recommended we also need to purchase a hosting plan for example1.com, which we've also done.

However, the redirect is still not working. I know the QR code should've never used HTTPS to begin with, but is there any other way around it to get this to work properly?

Comment: Can you tell us more about how the hosting is set up, the SSL is configured, and the redirect is configured?  It sounds like the way that you hosting company had you set things up should work.  Or can you tell us the actual URL so that we can test it?

Comment: The advice from you hosting company may have been a bit self-serving for them and not your cheapest option.   I tend to use Cloudflare to redirect alternate domains with HTTPS support.  Its a bit of a pain to set up, but it works with their free tier of service.  See [Instructions for setting up an alternate redirect domoin with HTTPS using Cloudflare](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/113180/how-to-avoid-ssl-warnings-about-certificate-not-for-the-current-site-when-redire/129449#129449)

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could provide what error message your receiving.

Comment: Also, does the web hosting support php and does a regular page display on https?